# Why is "Get-Command -Module oneget" command not displaying the list of commands in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell, and I'm not getting the command list after executing the "Get-Command -Module oneget" command.

How do I get the list of commands, like Install-Package, Find-Package, etc. commands using the "Get-Command -Module oneget" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the PowerShell 5.0 preview build for getting the `OneGet` module. Ensure you have that installed. You can get it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42936

Comment: thanks ravikant but I am facing problem while installation like following error "Update not applicable to your computer".

Comment: Well, the WMF 5.0 preview is available only for Windows 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1. So, if you are not using any of those OS, you cannot install WMF 5.0 preview.

Comment: The link is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the command like this:`Get-Command -Module PackageManagement`

Comment: Please explain your answer.